# jquery .text() updating "source" but not the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my jquery scenario:

1. User click on div
2. It triggers an ajax call to save some data on DB
3. when callback received, we show an update msg <--everything good
   until here
4. Now, when user click on the same element, it shows the information
   from the DB, the same should happen with the other divs!

Noticed that when you click, the same text that you saved later is showing up in all the divs!!! it is not refreshing, but the actual source IS showing 
the changes!

It looks like only the DOM is not reflecting the changes!

I am trying to put the text in the divs using .text();

All the divs are using the same element id!, I am just updating its data!

Thanks,

Marco

Comment: "All the divs are using the same element id!," that might be your problem right there. Elements need unique ids.

Comment: All the div having same element Id?

Comment: please share some relevant code / html so that we can help you better.

Comment: Let me add them an id and try!

Comment: Are you still having problems? Have you tried switching to classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`All the divs are using the same element id!` - never ever should two elements have the same ID, because it breaks the principles on which HTML is built on and 3rd party libraries rely on.

If you need to target multiple elements use **classes**.

In case your elements have the class `yourClass` and you want to set them the text "foo", then

```
var yourResponseText = "foo";
$('.yourClass').text(yourResponseText);
```

Especially if you use jQuery - the ID selector is implemented in such way, that when it finds an element with that ID it doesn't look for another - the settings will only affect the first (from the viewpoint of DOM) element. On the other hand, when you're using the class selector, then simply said you're doing a *forEach* cycle through the elements with that class.